# PHP File Upload security

Tags: php

I have a script that upload files to my server here is my code

When a user uploads a file to the server

1. My script renames the file and save the details in db.
2. I place files outside of web root.

so is my approach safe?

Comment: Please dont use mysql_* function those are deprricated check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171640/176320

Comment: @ranjith can you post that peace of code so I can work with it? because it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do further input validation on your file, like:

- check the file size
- check the file type with a "File Type Recogniser"
- check content header

You can also check best practices for file uploads here:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

Never run the file on your server.

to check content type (i've never done this myself btw) you can try soemthing like:

```
$file = "path2file";
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type = $finfo->file($file);
if(in_array($type,array("application/zip", "application/x-zip", .. whatever content types are ok...)))
  //you passed
```

Comment: please see this it already checks the extension $ext = explode('.', $files['name'][$i]);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext)); then I also check the files mime type I store that data in db.

Comment: Can you show me example for content header? so I can implement it

Comment: @Danish :but this is not the right way to check the file extension. cause a `filename` can have more than one `dots` . like this `new.image.jpg || new.image.png` . For that, you can go for built in function of `pathinfo($filename)`, it will be safe one.

Comment: @Tucker : I hav one doubt. I upload my all files inside of project dir. is it secure one?

Comment: the file security depends on how it's accessed and what you need security wise- the file will likely do no hard if it simply sits there unread by the web application :-)   that is until you run out of space!

Comment: @Ranjith : I don't know why you said that it is not the right way but I already checked that lets say I have an image called abc.png so now according your theory I rename it to abc.php.png or I save as an image called abc.png.exe so my script doesn't uploads abc.png.exe but uploads as png image abc.php.png and I think that is correct?

Comment: @Tucker : I'll try your code and post it back here but I have one question since I'm allowing any file type except .exe and my server isn't executing it so is there still any security risks?

Comment: @Danish ok, fyi my php code for the content type might need some fiddling with since i've never done it with php.  I'm curious to see what works

Comment: @Danish : Can you explain how to file extension check works? I got Only the `error` message of `not allow...` And what you stored in `$_files['name'] ` ?. I think its name of the file like `abc.png` right?

Comment: @Ranjith yes you are right `$_files['name']` stores the file name like `abc.png` and lets say if you are trying to upload like you said with double extension `abc.png.exe` it will show error `not allowed` other wise if it is passed through white list it will uploaded something abc.exe.png will be accepted because it will still be image.

Comment: @Danish : Ya. I understand what  you are trying to say, Lets see, I just workout with your code checks the extension alone(not try to upload) . Before your `for loop` I simply assigned the `$_files['name'] = 'abc.png';` Now I run the code, I got only error message `not allow..`. I dont change anything in your `for loop`.

Comment: @Danish : And one more thing, In `for loop` you get the `count('$_files['name]')` . It will returns as 1 for the all the time. I think you could change into `strlen($_files['name'])`.

Comment: @Ranjith Did you tried uploading multiple images? I tried it and it is working I mean uploading that means it should return correct?

Comment: @Tucker I tried your code but it gives me following error `

Warning: finfo::file() [finfo.file]: File or path not found 'test.php' in` where test.php is a file I'm trying to upload.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26291/discussion-between-ranjith-and-danish)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is safe. because all files will upload outside of web root. no one can access it directly via URL.